# TCPDump and IPTables DROP by string

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, wireshark, tcpdump

by using `tcpdump -nlASX -s 0 -vvv port 80` I get something like:

```
14:58:55.121160 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 49764, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1480)
    206.72.206.58.http > 2.187.196.7.4624: Flags [.], cksum 0x6900 (incorrect -> 0xcd18), seq 1672149449:1672150889, ack 4202197968, win 15340, length 1440
        0x0000:  4500 05c8 c264 4000 4006 0f86 ce48 ce3a  E....d@.@....H.:
        0x0010:  02bb c407 0050 1210 63aa f9c9 fa78 73d0  .....P..c....xs.
        0x0020:  5010 3bec 6900 0000 0f29 95cc fac4 2854  P.;.i....)....(T
        0x0030:  c0e7 3384 e89a 74fa 8d8c a069 f93f fc40  ..3...t....i.?.@
        0x0040:  1561 af61 1cf3 0d9c 3460 aa23 0b54 aac0  .a.a....4`.#.T..
        0x0050:  5090 ced1 b7bf 8857 c476 e1c0 8814 81ed  P......W.v......
        0x0060:  9e85 87e8 d693 b637 bd3a 56ef c5fa 77e8  .......7.:V...w.
        0x0070:  3035 743a 283e 89c7 ced8 c7c1 cff9 6ca3  05t:(>........l.
        0x0080:  5f3f 0162 ebf1 419e c410 7180 7cd0 29e1  _?.b..A...q.|.).
        0x0090:  fec9 c708 0f01 9b2f a96b 20fe b95a 31cf  ......./.k...Z1.
        0x00a0:  8166 3612 bac9 4e8d 7087 4974 0063 1270  .f6...N.p.It.c.p
```

What do I pull to use IPTables to block via string. Or is there a better way to block attacks that have something in common?

Question is:
Can I pick any piece from that IP packet and call it a string?

```
iptables -A INPUT -m string --alog bm --string attack_string -j DROP
```

In other words:
In some cases I can ban with TTL=xxx and use that should an attack have the same TTL. Sure it will block some legit packets but if it means keeping the box up it works till the attack goes away but I would like to LEARN how to FIND other common things in a packet to block with IPTables

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking for. Your iptables command looks right. What are you missing?

Comment: I'm not sure what I can call a string from an IP Packet

Comment: Why would you call a string? What does that even mean?

Comment: Maybe you can use a L7 filter?  what data is this?

Comment: I'm just looking to find a way to block ALL packets that have something in common to put an end to small syn type floods. :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on "something in common"? From the point of view of filtering there's a big difference between "has value 0x4012 20 bytes into the IP payload" and "contains the string 'large wooden rabbit' somewhere".

Comment: Like in some cases I can ban with TTL=xxx and use that should an attack have the same TTL. Sure it will block some legit packets but if it means keeping the box up it works till the attack goes away but I would like to LEARN how to FIND other common things in a packet to block with IPTables

Comment: typo: --alog bm should be --algo bm

Answer (score 2):

`iptables -A INPUT -m string --alog bm --string attack_string -j DROP`

There's a couple of problems with this idea.

First you should see the relevant [documentation](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-extensions-HOWTO-3.html):

> Please do use this match with caution. A lot of people want to use
>   this match to stop worms, along with the DROP target. This is a major
>   mistake. It would be defeated by any IDS evasion method.
>
> In a similar fashion, a lot of people have been using this match as a
>   mean to stop particular functions in HTTP like POST or GET by dropping
>   any HTTP packet containing the string POST. Please understand that
>   this job is better done by a filtering proxy. Additionally, any HTML
>   content with the word POST would get dropped with the former method.
>   This match has been designed to be able to queue to userland
>   interesting packets for better analysis, that's all. Dropping packet
>   based on this would be defeated by any IDS evasion method.

What the `-string` directive is really for is for placing packets in a separate queue or chain for processing by an IDS system. It's not designed to interpret Layer-7 information either holistically/behaviorally or by using signature matching and then dropping it once it is determined to be "bad". So secondly, the `-string` directive is not sophisticated enough for your use case and you'll likely end up dropping packets you want to keep.

You'll also notice there is no string in the packet you can feed to `-string`. The packet as shown by TCPDump is unreadable once translated to (presumably) ASCI. The `-string` argument is really designed for looking for things like HTTP Post commands where you do have strings in the packet. If you wanted to follow through with your idea of using iptables as a signature matching IDS system you probably want to use the [U3](http://www.stearns.org/doc/iptables-u32.v0.1.7.html) Matching capability to look for particular bit-patterns.

Third, and most importantly, by the time the packets involved in a Denial-of-Service reach your machine and are being processed by your firewall the damage is already done. Any significant mitigation of a Denial-of-Service attack will involve working with your upstream provider to block the traffic *before* it reaches your server.

Answer (score -1):

Your last comment seems to indicate that you are looking for a way to mediate syn floods.  Syn Cookies are designed to do just that.  You can enable syncookies with the following command run as root.

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies
```

There are other settings you can tweak to change the behavior of syn cookies.  See the documentation at http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt.

Comment: syncookies never work. ;/ at least in ddos attacks of bigger sizes.